# How to use an owner drawn rich edit control

Tags: winapi

I'm using a Rich Edit Control on Windows. I tried passing the value `SS_OWNERDRAWN` to the `CreateWindowEx` call but it appears to have had no effect. How can I prevent the rich edit control from drawing anything so that I can owner draw it?

I also attempted to set a window subclass that simply ignored `WM_PAINT` but forwarded all other messages. This had an immensely nasty effect on my whole system and also caused my application to halt.

Edit: Apparently, the system still expects BeginPaint and EndPaint in response to WM_PAINT, even if you return 0 and don't paint anything. My system no longer dies and and my app no longer halts, and the rich edit is certainly no longer painting anything, but I still can't render my Direct3D9 text in that area. :(

Edit: Turns out that, in fact, you do not have ownership of the DC returned by `ID3DXFont::GetDC()`. Documentation unclear, but problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RichEdit controls do not support an owner-drawing window stye, so you cannot use `SS_OWNERDRAWN` or similar.

As for `WM_PAINT`, simply ignoring painting messages should not have caused such drastic side effects, so you must have done something else wrong.

Comment: Apparently, the system expects BeginPaint and EndPaint, even if you return that you handled the message and don't actually paint anything. Once I did this, the problem was somewhat solved- the RichEdit control no longer renders, but it still blocks my DirectX9 text rendering in that area.